# Change JSON object values in a Pythonic way

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

I have the following JSON object and I need to replace all None values with 0 (zero) within parameters keys.

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "x_pos": 0,
    "y_pos": None,
    "x_pos": 0,
    "...": None,
  },
}
```

I'm wondering if this can be done in a Pythonic way? And what that way is called (for example, List Comprehension). I think it might look something like this:

```py
params = j_obj.get('parameters')
for param in params:
  params[param] = params.get(param) if params.get(param) is not None else 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
j_obj['parameters'] = {a:0 if b is None else b for a, b in j_obj['parameters'].items()}
```

Comment: Thank you! is there any place I can study more about this kind of solution? For example, know all kinds of "comprehension" in python. You just taught me dictionary comprehension which I had no idea it existed, thank you for this!

Comment: @meetnick [This](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) is a good summary of both list and dictionary comprehensions. For reference, [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) is the official PEP on dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @meetnick Glad to help!